# Null checks for scala XML attributes

Tags: scala

How to avoid the attributes coming into the xml nodes having None type:

I tried below code but its not working:

```
scala> val checked:Option[String] = None
checked: Option[String] = None

scala> val xml = <input checked={checked} />
<console>:11: error: overloaded method constructor UnprefixedAttribute with alternatives:
(key: String,value: Option[Seq[scala.xml.Node]],next: scala.xml.MetaData)scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute <and>
(key: String,value: String,next: scala.xml.MetaData)scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute <and>
(key: String,value: Seq[scala.xml.Node],next1: scala.xml.MetaData)scala.xml.UnprefixedAttribute
cannot be applied to (String, Option[String], scala.xml.MetaData)
   val xml = <input checked={checked} />
```

Expected output is this:

```
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <input/>
```

If the type of the checked is xml.Text, then its working. so basically i want to insert attributes conditionally, if value is Some(type) then include the attribute if its None then ignore, how is it possible with type of attributes other than Xml.Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is incorrect type of `Option[String]` you should use `Option[scala.xml.Text]` instead. For example if you have `Option[String]` you can `map` it:

`val xml = <input checked={checked.map(scala.xml.Text.apply)}/>`.

or you can use

`val xml = <input checked={checked.orNull}/>`

But I think it is a little bit ugly to work with `null`.

Comment: does this scala.xml.Text.apply work for all data types including Integers/BigDecimal/DateTime?

Comment: I'm getting this error while using map on String type :
Type mismatch: expected (char) => NotInfferedB actual: (String) => Text

Comment: If i right understand we are talking about `Option[String]` not just `String`, so map will work clearly. About one another type, for example `Int`, you can map it with `scala.xml.Atom`. For the instance `val xml = <input checked={checked.map(new Atom(_)}/>`. And one more point, this also will work with  `Option[String]`.

Comment: How to do this for the whole tag?
exmple: <user field="Username" value="John" />
how to ignore complete User tag if value is None?

Comment: I'm trying this but not working
<users>
if(john.get("Surname") != None)
<user field="SurName" value={john.get("Surname")} />
</users>

Comment: Try `john.get("Surname").map(x => <users><user field="SurName" value={x} /> </users>)`

Comment: But o/p is not in desired format..its coming like this:
Some(&lt;user field=&quot;SurName&quot; value=&quot;Baker&quot;/&gt;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input checked = {checked.getOrElse(null)} />

>> xml: scala.xml.Elem = <input/>
```

Setting an attribute to null is the same as not having the attribute.

Comment: There are some circumstances in which it's okay.  This is one of them.  The XML parser correctly interprets a null as representing an attribute that should not be included in the XML.